# Time Complexity of String Comparison

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, time-complexity

I ran some test to determine if O(==) for Strings is O(len(string)) or O(1).

My tests:

```
import timeit
x = 'ab' * 500000000
y = 'ab' * 500000000
%timeit x == y

> 163 ms ± 4.62 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

x = 'ab' * 5000
y = 'ab' * 5000
%timeit x == y

> 630 ns ± 23.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Looking at the above results I understand that string comparison is linear O(N) and not O(1).

However, I was reading this document: [Complexities of Python Operations](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/ICS-33/lectures/complexitypython.txt)

The part:

*Finally, when comparing two lists for equality, the complexity class above shows as O(N), but in reality we would need to multiply this complexity class by O==(...) where O==(...) is the complexity class for checking whether two values in the list are ==. If they are ints, O==(...) would be O(1); if they are strings, O==(...) in the worst case it would be O(len(string)). This issue applies any time an == check is done. We mostly will assume == checking on values in lists is O(1): e.g., checking ints and small/fixed-length strings.*

This says the worst case for strings would be O(len(string)). My question is why worst case? Shouldn't the best/average case be O(len(string))?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The algorithm is simple, you check the strings char by char, so:

```
Hello == Hello => They are equal...so it is actually the worst case because you check all the chars from both strings
Hello != Hella => Still worst case, you realize they are different in the last char of the strings.
hello != Hello => Best case scenario, the first char for both (h != H) are different, so you stop checking them there.
```

Comment: What about strings that are equal? Would it be O(1)?

Comment: @Hello.World No, they are still `O(N)` because you dont know if they are equal until you check all of the individual chars are equal. Only best case scenario where the first char pair checking is different would be `O(1)`

Comment: So immutability of strings in no way affects the equality check right?

Comment: Not in this case, they are immutable for other reasons.

Comment: Python doesn't by default do the "hashing test" to rule out obviously non-equal strings?